# Realm Browser crash when I click on a table

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration

I'm using the free version of Realm Object Server (Ubuntu). I've tried to check my database but the Realm Browser (1.7) keep crashing. Every time I click on a specific table.

I have noticed if I change the structure of an entity, it will update the database automatically. Maybe the Realm Browser crashed because I haven't used the migration? Any idea?

[List of my tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn3Rc.png)

[Card is empty should be 25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgL7R.png)

If I click on User --> Crash

```
    Incident Identifier: 69BAA01D-ADA3-4E03-9DDF-6F0DB181C801
CrashReporter Key:   DDC68D85-8351-5EA0-B0F7-3C26841B8B96
Hardware Model:      MacBookPro11,3
Process:         Realm Browser [46119]
Path:            
Identifier:      io.realm.realmbrowser
Version:         2.1.7 (91)
Code Type:       X86-64
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2017-04-19T16:04:57Z
Launch Time:     2017-04-18T16:07:07Z
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.11.5 (15F34)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_MAPERR at 0x178
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
Selector name found in current argument registers: index

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   Realm                                0x0000000100a131fc 0x1009cd000 + 287228
1   Realm                                0x0000000100a94bab 0x1009cd000 + 818091
2   Realm                                0x0000000100a94ce6 0x1009cd000 + 818406
3   Realm Browser                        0x00000001007dff5d 0x1007d8000 + 32605
4   Realm Browser                        0x00000001007f64b2 0x1007d8000 + 124082
5   Realm Browser                        0x00000001007df1a6 0x1007d8000 + 29094
6   Realm Browser                        0x00000001007f2a1b 0x1007d8000 + 109083
7   Realm Browser                        0x00000001007e8dff 0x1007d8000 + 69119
8   Realm Browser                        0x0000000100800cee 0x1007d8000 + 167150
9   Realm Browser                        0x0000000100800b88 0x1007d8000 + 166792
10  CoreFoundation                       0x00007fff93079bbc __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
11  CoreFoundation                       0x00007fff93079b4f ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 63
12  CoreFoundation                       0x00007fff93079ac7 _CFXRegistrationPost + 407
13  CoreFoundation                       0x00007fff93079832 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
14  CoreFoundation                       0x00007fff930365e2 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1922
15  CoreFoundation                       0x00007fff93035835 _CFXNotificationPost + 693
16  Foundation                           0x00007fff9739217a -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
17  AppKit                               0x00007fff9dcbff9c -[NSTableView _sendSelectionChangedNotificationForRows:columns:] + 175
18  AppKit                               0x00007fff9dc1cfe3 -[NSTableView _enableSelectionPostingAndPost] + 424
19  AppKit                               0x00007fff9de04679 -[NSTableView mouseDown:] + 5358
20  AppKit                               0x00007fff9de02f52 -[NSOutlineView mouseDown:] + 74
21  AppKit                               0x00007fff9e2d83c9 -[NSWindow _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 6322
22  AppKit                               0x00007fff9e2d93ad -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 212
23  AppKit                               0x00007fff9dd18539 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 517
24  AppKit                               0x00007fff9dc98a38 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2540
25  HockeySDK                            0x000000010088a54e 0x10087a000 + 66894
26  AppKit                               0x00007fff9daffdf2 -[NSApplication run] + 796
27  AppKit                               0x00007fff9dac9368 NSApplicationMain + 1176
28  libdyld.dylib                        0x00007fff9bf2d5ad start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00007fff8ee2befa kevent_qos + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib                    0x00007fff97bdadcd _dispatch_autorelease_pool_pop + 0
```

Cheers

Alain

Comment: You need to post some code and the error messages before we can help you. Otherwise we would be guessing.

Comment: It would be great if you can share more info how to reproduce this issue and a stack trace (if you have one) after the crash. Thanks!

Comment: It's really hard to give you some codes however, I can post the stack trace. Basically, I have changed the data structure (add few more fields). I don't know why, the Realm Browser keep crashing.

Comment: What version of which platform was the Realm file created by?

Comment: Version 1.3, it's a fresh install.